# How to call a method in tkinter from an imported package?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a python script that records screen but now when I try to use tkinter to have my screen recording script run and terminate from the buttons in tk window I am facing the following issue:

> *self.recorderButton = Button(frame, text="Start Recording", command=self.Recorder.record_screen) AttributeError: 'Trial' object
>   has no attribute 'Recorder*'

**Here is my python code:**

```
from tkinter import *
import Recorder

class Trial:

    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        # self.printButton = Button(frame, text="Print Message", command=self.printMessage)
        # self.printButton.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.recorderButton = Button(frame, text="Start Recording", command=self.Recorder.record_screen)
        self.recorderButton.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.quitButton = Button(frame, text="Quit", command=frame.quit)
        self.quitButton.pack(side=LEFT)

    def printMessage(self):
        print("Hello there its me Nitin!")

root = Tk()
alpha = Trial(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

`record_screen()` is a function that belongs to `Recorder` module. So prefixing it with self does not make sense.

I mean you should write the callback as follows:

```
self.recorderButton = Button(frame, text="Start Recording", command=Recorder.record_screen)
```

**EDIT:**

For the question through your comment.

When you code this option for a button `command = something`, that `something` must be a callback (function), and I guess you did not implement  that callback somewhere.

You can add this function inside your class:

```
def quit(self):
    self.frame.destroy()
```

**And** change (`...command=self.frame.quit`) to (`...command=self.quit`)

Comment: @Bilal BEGUERADJ i tried your answer , the program runs now but it simply won't terminate when i click 'quit' button

Comment: i did exactly that , but the code still doesen't terminate